# Determine Hadoop cluster resources used by completed job

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

How can you determine Hadoop cluster resources used by a completed job?

Our cluster resource manager is `yarn`.  Access to certain yarn API endpoints is available through HTTP; for example:

```
curl -L http://my.hadoop.instance:8088/ws/v1/cluster/apps/application_1547448533998_502644
```

would return:

```
{
    "app": {
        "allocatedMB": -1,
        "allocatedVCores": -1,
        "amContainerLogs": "http://someNode.hadoop.instance:8042/node/containerlogs/container_e149_1547448533998_502644_01_000001/someUser",
        "amHostHttpAddress": "someNode.hadoop.instance:8042",
        "amNodeLabelExpression": "",
        "applicationTags": "",
        "applicationType": "SPARK",
        "clusterId": 1547448533998,
        "clusterUsagePercentage": 0.0,
        "diagnostics": "",
        "elapsedTime": 583889,
        "finalStatus": "SUCCEEDED",
        "finishedTime": 1550621490747,
        "id": "application_1547448533998_502644",
        "logAggregationStatus": "TIME_OUT",
        "memorySeconds": 15821179,
        "name": "ProjectCantor",
        "numAMContainerPreempted": 0,
        "numNonAMContainerPreempted": 0,
        "preemptedResourceMB": 0,
        "preemptedResourceVCores": 0,
        "priority": 0,
        "progress": 100.0,
        "queue": "dsg",
        "queueUsagePercentage": 0.0,
        "runningContainers": -1,
        "startedTime": 1550620906858,
        "state": "FINISHED",
        "trackingUI": "History",
        "trackingUrl": "http://my.hadoop.instance:8088/proxy/application_1547448533998_502644/",
        "unmanagedApplication": false,
        "user": "someUser",
        "vcoreSeconds": 14713
    }
}
```

However, there are several attributes such as `allocatedMB` and `allocatedVCores` set to `-1` rather than any meaningful value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The YARN Resource Manager REST APIs typically refer to instantaneous values and since your job completed the -1s show no current usage.  Is `mapred job -status <JOB_ID>` what you're looking for?

Comment: I used `spark-submit` to start the job in question; hence, there is an application ID that indexes logs archived by `yarn`.  But so far, it doesn't look like there is a "job ID".  `yarn` shows that our `Application-Type` is `SPARK`, not `MAPREDUCE`, so I suspect the `mapred` CLI doesn't work here.

Comment: You can try by changing "application_" to "job_" in the application ID but I imagine you're right as I believe MapReduce implemented counters within the AM and other parts of it's framework to measure all the resources used.

Comment: Look at the Spark History server.  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html . Based on the provided APIs it should give better metrics.